# HERE Api Maps calculated route not following overland roads

Tags: rest, routes, gps, here-api, here-maps-rest

I am obtaining route information from the HERE Maps Routing API using this REST call:

```
"https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?" +
         "waypoint0=34.045535,-118.222708&waypoint1=34.045142,-118.235551" +
         "&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled&departure=now&app_id=[appID]&app_code=[appCode]"
```

The call works and this is the response:

```
{
    "response": {
      "metaInfo": {
        "timestamp": "2020-04-05T09:06:42Z",
        "mapVersion": "8.30.107.152",
        "moduleVersion": "7.2.202013-6774",
        "interfaceVersion": "2.6.76",
        "availableMapVersion": [
          "8.30.107.152"
        ]
      },
      "route": [
        {
          "waypoint": [
            {
              "linkId": "-1252788623",
              "mappedPosition": {
                "latitude": 34.0452509,
                "longitude": -118.2226727
              },
              "originalPosition": {
                "latitude": 34.0455349,
                "longitude": -118.222708
              },
              "type": "stopOver",
              "spot": 0.4571429,
              "sideOfStreet": "right",
              "mappedRoadName": "E 3rd St",
              "label": "E 3rd St",
              "shapeIndex": 0,
              "source": "user"
            },
            {
              "linkId": "+23907924",
              "mappedPosition": {
                "latitude": 34.0450604,
                "longitude": -118.2356195
              },
              "originalPosition": {
                "latitude": 34.045142,
                "longitude": -118.235551
              },
              "type": "stopOver",
              "spot": 0.6229508,
              "sideOfStreet": "right",
              "mappedRoadName": "Traction Ave",
              "label": "Traction Ave",
              "shapeIndex": 20,
              "source": "user"
            }
          ],
          "mode": {
            "type": "fastest",
            "transportModes": [
              "car"
            ],
            "trafficMode": "disabled",
            "feature": []
          },
          "leg": [
            {
              "start": {
                "linkId": "-1252788623",
                "mappedPosition": {
                  "latitude": 34.0452509,
                  "longitude": -118.2226727
                },
                "originalPosition": {
                  "latitude": 34.0455349,
                  "longitude": -118.222708
                },
                "type": "stopOver",
                "spot": 0.4571429,
                "sideOfStreet": "right",
                "mappedRoadName": "E 3rd St",
                "label": "E 3rd St",
                "shapeIndex": 0,
                "source": "user"
              },
              "end": {
                "linkId": "+23907924",
                "mappedPosition": {
                  "latitude": 34.0450604,
                  "longitude": -118.2356195
                },
                "originalPosition": {
                  "latitude": 34.045142,
                  "longitude": -118.235551
                },
                "type": "stopOver",
                "spot": 0.6229508,
                "sideOfStreet": "right",
                "mappedRoadName": "Traction Ave",
                "label": "Traction Ave",
                "shapeIndex": 20,
                "source": "user"
              },
              "length": 1743,
              "travelTime": 201,
              "maneuver": [
                {
                  "position": {
                    "latitude": 34.0452509,
                    "longitude": -118.2226727
                  },
                  "instruction": "Head <span class=\"heading\">west</span> on <span class=\"street\">E 3rd St</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Go for <span class=\"length\">39 m</span>.</span>",
                  "travelTime": 19,
                  "length": 39,
                  "id": "M1",
                  "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
                },
                {
                  "position": {
                    "latitude": 34.0452147,
                    "longitude": -118.2231045
                  },
                  "instruction": "Turn <span class=\"direction\">left</span> onto <span class=\"next-street\">S Gless St</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Go for <span class=\"length\">258 m</span>.</span>",
                  "travelTime": 46,
                  "length": 258,
                  "id": "M2",
                  "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
                },
                {
                  "position": {
                    "latitude": 34.0429187,
                    "longitude": -118.2227612
                  },
                  "instruction": "Turn <span class=\"direction\">right</span> onto <span class=\"next-street\">E 4th St</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Go for <span class=\"length\">1.1 km</span>.</span>",
                  "travelTime": 84,
                  "length": 1120,
                  "id": "M3",
                  "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
                },
                {
                  "position": {
                    "latitude": 34.0429831,
                    "longitude": -118.2341015
                  },
                  "instruction": "Turn <span class=\"direction\">right</span> onto <span class=\"next-street\">Merrick St</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Go for <span class=\"length\">112 m</span>.</span>",
                  "travelTime": 20,
                  "length": 112,
                  "id": "M4",
                  "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
                },
                {
                  "position": {
                    "latitude": 34.043895,
                    "longitude": -118.2338119
                  },
                  "instruction": "Continue on <span class=\"next-street\">Traction Ave</span>. <span class=\"distance-description\">Go for <span class=\"length\">214 m</span>.</span>",
                  "travelTime": 32,
                  "length": 214,
                  "id": "M5",
                  "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
                },
                {
                  "position": {
                    "latitude": 34.0450604,
                    "longitude": -118.2356195
                  },
                  "instruction": "Arrive at <span class=\"street\">Traction Ave</span>. Your destination is on the right.",
                  "travelTime": 0,
                  "length": 0,
                  "id": "M6",
                  "_type": "PrivateTransportManeuverType"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "summary": {
            "distance": 1743,
            "trafficTime": 203,
            "baseTime": 201,
            "flags": [
              "builtUpArea"
            ],
            "text": "The trip takes <span class=\"length\">1.7 km</span> and <span class=\"time\">3 mins</span>.",
            "travelTime": 201,
            "_type": "RouteSummaryType"
          }
        }
      ],
      "language": "en-us"
    }
}
```

It is valid, except that it does not seem to include all the link points for the route. This screen shot of the resulting route is quite self-explanatory:

[image: given route (red line) does not conform to the actual route (green line)]

The API returns link points that chart out the red line, instead of the green line, which should be the actual overland route.

Am I missing any attributes that may be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try considering the mode to traffic:enabled

With disabled mode :
No departure time provided:

Static time based restrictions: Ignored
Real-time traffic closures: Ignored.
Real-time traffic flow speed: Ignored.
Historical and predictive traffic: Ignored

Departure time provided:

Static time based restrictions: Avoided if road would be traversed within validity period of the restriction.
Real-time traffic closures: Valid for entire length of route.
Real-time traffic flow speed: Ignored.
Historical and predictive traffic: Ignored

Note: Difference between traffic disabled and enabled affects only the calculation of the route. Traffic time of the route will still be calculated for all routes using the same rules as for traffic:enabled.

Also refer below example for car routing : 
https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/routing

Comment: Thank you for the pointers; most helpful. The feature I was looking for appears to be the *navigation shape*. However, the data associated with the shape is quite large. Is there any way to trim the response package to return only the array of route coordinates?